# C# - Check if dictionary contains null values via mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

Is there a way to check if dictionary contains any null values with mongodb driver for c#?

Im trying to check this and i get System.ArgumentException.

Here is the query:

```
var findResults = await _db.collection
                .FindAsync(x => x.Id1 == id1 && x.Results.Values.Contains(null));
```

here is the data object:

```
public class FileExport
{
    public Guid Id1 { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<FileType, Guid?> Results { get; set; }
}

public enum FileType
{
    CSV,
    JSON,
    XML

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it Serializable ? Shouldn't dictionary keys be strings when you try to save them in MongoDB ?

Comment: I'm not familiar to MongoDB but if in `x.Results.Values.Contains(null)` `x.Results.Values` is a generic `List<T>` you can say `x.Results.Values.Any(v => v == null)` to check if there is a null value, I guess it is the cause of `System.ArgumentException`

Comment: It is Serializable. x.Results.Values.Any(v => v == null) throw exception also.

Comment: @asdf I tried to create an instance of `FileExport` and save it in my local db but the driver says that: `When using DictionaryRepresentation.Document key values must serialize as strings.` which makes sense in my opinion. So am I missing something ?